# Mongoose updating nested subdocuments

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update sub documents with mongoose using the `request.body` without passing of the sub documents `_id`. Updating works but mongoose is removing the `_id` from the sub documents.

Assume the following schemas

```
// schemas.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const motorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    type: String,
    volume: Number,
});

const carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    manufacturer: String,
    model: String,
    motors: [motorSchema],
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   email: String,
   cars: [carSchema]
});
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
// import schemas
const userSchema = require('userSchema');
const carSchema = require('carSchema');
const motorSchema = require('motorSchema');
// create models
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Car = mongoose.model("Car", carSchema);
const Motor = mongoose.model("Motor", motorSchema);

module.exports.updateCar = async function (request, response) {
    const condition = {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(request.body.userId),
        "cars._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectIt(request.body.carId)
        };

    // Build object for partial update
    const set = {};
    for(let field in reqest.body){
        set[`cars.$.${field}`] = request.body[field];
    }

    const update = {
        $set = set;
    }

    User.findOneAndUpdate(condition, update, {new: true, overwrite: false},
        (error, user) => {
            if(error) {response.send(error)}
            response.json(user);
        }
}
```

The problem is that all my `_id` properties will be overwritten in the motors array. How can I force mongoose as default to not change the `_id` properties?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, the equivalent mongoDB syntax will use `arrayFilters`, so you can modify your query to use that as well:

For example:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  condition,
  {$set: {"cars.$[item].size": "large"}},
  {arrayFilters: [{"item._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectIt(request.body.carId)}]}
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0UmnPeZOn6Z)

According to this method, your code needs the `arrayFilters` in the options part and the `$[<identifier>]` in the `$set` part of the query:

```
const set = {};
    for(let field in reqest.body){
        set[`cars.$[item].${field}`] = request.body[field];
    }

    const update = {
        $set = set;
    }

    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        condition, 
        update, 
        {
            arrayFilters: [{"item._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectIt(request.body.carId)}],
            new: true, overwrite: false
        },
        (error, user) => {
            if(error) {response.send(error)}
            response.json(user);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your answer. I have to see if I can include this. I will accept the answer when everything works out :).